# How can I return post API message?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have some messages in the API side. I want to return API Message to user when the "Success" status is false. I was able to print the messages in the get operations, but not in the post operation.

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddUser(UserModel userModel, string uniqueUser)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var postTask = _client.PostAsJsonAsync<UserModel>("users/adduser", userModel);
            postTask.Wait();
            var result = postTask.Result;

            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("AddApplicant", "Applicant", new { uniqueUser = uniqueUser });
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Response Model

```
public class ResponseModel
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

User Model

```
public class UserModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "E-Mail")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} field is requried.")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Your {0} information is not in the correct format.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} field is requried.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Your {0} information is not in correct format.")]
    public string PhoneNumber1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Second Phone Number")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Your {0} information is not in correct format.")]
    public string PhoneNumber2 { get; set; }

}
```

API response
[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `ResponseModel` isn't being used anywhere, how is it relevant?  What is `UserModel`?  Where specifically are you trying to "print the message"?  What specifically isn't working as expected in the code shown?

Comment: Where I can use ResponseModel when post process?

Comment: @mustafasamet: You can use your class wherever you like.  Currently you're simply *not using it anywhere*.  It's really not clear what you're asking.

Comment: (As an aside... The code shown is making improper use of asynchronous operations.  Don't call `.Wait()` or `.Result` on a `Task` directly.  Make your method `async` and use `await`.)

Comment: Where should I use the response model class to return the message to the user? this is my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost... Use `async` properly.  Don't call `.Wait()` or `.Result` directly.  Instead, `await` the task:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddUser(UserModel userModel, string uniqueUser)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync<UserModel>("users/adduser", userModel);
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("AddApplicant", "Applicant", new { uniqueUser = uniqueUser });
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

This will make further interactions with the result much simpler.  As for your "message", first you need to deserialize the result:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddUser(UserModel userModel, string uniqueUser)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync<UserModel>("users/adduser", userModel);
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // deserialize the response:
            var response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var responseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(response);

            return RedirectToAction("AddApplicant", "Applicant", new { uniqueUser = uniqueUser });
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Then you can do whatever you like with that `.Message` property.  For example, you can include it in the redirect parameters:

```
// deserialize the response:
var response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var responseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(response);

return RedirectToAction("AddApplicant", "Applicant", new
    {
        uniqueUser = uniqueUser,
        message = responseModel.Message
    });
```

Or in something like `TempData`:

```
// deserialize the response:
var response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var responseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(response);

TempData["message"] = responseModel.Message;
return RedirectToAction("AddApplicant", "Applicant", new { uniqueUser = uniqueUser });
```

Overall the pattern is the same.  In order to use the `Message` you first need to read it from the response.  Then you can use it however you like.

Comment: Thank very very much. You did really big thing again!!